# How to create a random distribution with no specific definition? Is uniform_int_distribution inheriting from other class?

Tags: c++, random

I want to create a piece of code that use a type called `Number` that may be a floating point number or any integer number (such `uint64_t`). I have the variable `dist` that is the distribution that should be used to generate random numbers, but it should be different in any of those cases, so i would like to do something like:

```
constexpr bool number_is_floating = std::is_floating_point<Number>::value;
#if number_is_floating
std::uniform_real_distribution<Number> dist(1.0, 1000.0);
#else
std::uniform_int_distribution<Number> dist(1, 1000);
#endif
```

But of course this is not going to work, because preprocessor variables get evaluated before the constant `number_is_floating` does, so this expression will always be false. I actually tried to do this:

```
Number getran() {
    if constexpr (number_is_floating)
        return std::uniform_real_distribution<Number>(1.0, 1000.0)(eng);
    else
        return std::uniform_int_distribution<Number>(1, 1000)(eng);
}
```

But this is not working because we are trying to compile code that inits `uniform_int_distribution` with a type that may or may not be integer (and the same for the real distribution).

What is the best and most-elegant way to make this code works even if `Number` is or not floating point?

Comment: A [mcve] would help, together with error messages you are getting.

Comment: `if constexpr` will only ignore code in the false branch during template instantiation (because it won't instantiate the unnecessary block). Using it in a function like this needs both code blocks to be compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this is not working because we are trying to compile code that inits uniform_int_distribution with a type that may or may not be integer (and the same for the real distribution).

No, `if constexpr` is evaluated at compile time and only one of the branches is compiled, the other is discarded, e.g. *not* compiled. Something like this compiles and works as (probably) intended:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename TNumber>
TNumber getran() {
    static std::default_random_engine eng; // Just to avoid undefined variables

    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<TNumber>::value) 
        return std::uniform_real_distribution<TNumber>(1.0, 1000.0)(eng);
    else
        return std::uniform_int_distribution<TNumber>(1, 1000)(eng);
}

int main()
{   
    std::cout << getran<float>() << ", "
              << getran<int>() << ", "
              << getran<double>() << ", "
              << getran<unsigned>();
}
```

Comment: Just note the fact that the number type HAS to be as a template of the function (as you have it as TNumber), otherwise, even if we are using an `if constexpr` you will get the error `error: static assertion failed: value has to be a floating point`(In GCC).

Answer (score 1):

```
Number getran_internal(std::integral_constant<bool, true> is_floating) {
  return std::uniform_real_distribution<Number>(1.0, 1000.0)(eng);
}
Number getran_internal(std::integral_constant<bool, false> is_floating) {
  return std::uniform_int_distribution<Number>(1, 1000)(eng);
}
Number getran() {
  return getran_internal( std::integral_constant<bool, number_is_floating>{} );
}
```

one way, of many.

Which way is ideal will depend on your compiler's support for various C++11 and above features.  this one should work with any [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a template function and use the corresponding distribution when implementing it for each particular type.

```
typedef std::default_random_engine generator;
typedef float Number;

template <typename T>
T next_random_number(generator &g);

template<>
float next_random_number<float>(generator &g) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(1.0, 1000.0);
    return dist(g);
}

template<>
int next_random_number<int>(generator &g) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 1000);
    return dist(g);
}

Number next(generator &g) {
    return next_random_number<Number>(g);
}

int main() {
    std::random_device r;
    generator g(r());

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << next(g) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Hope I correctly understand your question.